# Convert binary string to list of integers using Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Slice a long binary string into 3 digit-long chunks.
2. Store each "chunk" into a list called row.
3. Convert each binary chunk into a number (0-7).
4. Store the converted list of numbers into a new list called numbers.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def traverse(R):
        x = 0
        while x < (len(R) - 3):
            row = R[x] + R[x+1] + R[x+2]
            ???
```

Thanks for your help! It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: and **how** you're trying to do this? or we should just give you teh c0dez?

Comment: I'll post what I have so far, although it probably is the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
s = "110101001"
numbers = [int(s[i:i+3], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
print numbers
```

The output is:

```
[6, 5, 1]
```

Breaking this down step by step, first:

```
>>> range(0, len(s), 3)
[0, 3, 6]
```

The [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) function produces a list of integers from 0, less than the max `len(s)`, by step 3.

```
>>> [s[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
["110", "101", "001"]
```

This is a [*list comprehension*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that evaluates `s[i:i+3]` for each `i` in the above range. The `s[i:i+3]` is a [*slice*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) that selects a substring. Finally:

```
>>> [int(s[i:i+3], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
[6, 5, 1]
```

The [`int(..., 2)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) function converts from binary (base 2, second argument) to integers.

Note that the above code may not properly handle error conditions like an input string that is not a multiple of 3 characters in length.

Comment: Great answer. The breakdown is particularly helpful if you don't understand the syntax of list comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks! You're answer is explained very clearly. I have one question though, what if the reference string is not a multiple of three? Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Nice one, it should be example python power and syntac :)

Comment: @unknown: If the string length is not a multiple of three, the above code will still execute without error. The shorter group of characters at the end will be interpreted as if it had leading zeros, eg. "1111" will be treated the same as "111001" and not "111100".

Answer (score 7):

I'll assume that by "binary string" you actually mean a normal string (i.e. text) whose items are all '0' or '1'.

So for points 1 and 2,

```
row = [thestring[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(thestring), 3)]
```

of course the last item will be only 1 or 2 characters long if `len(thestring)` is not an exact multiple of 3, that's inevitable;-).

For points 3 and 4, I'd suggest building an auxiliary temp dictionary and storing it:

```
aux = {}
for x in range(8):
  s = format(x, 'b')
  aux[s] = x
  aux[('00'+s)[-3:]] = x
```

so that points 3 and 4 just become:

```
numbers = [aux[x] for x in row]
```

this dict lookup should be much faster than converting each entry on the fly.

**Edit**: it's been suggested I explain why am I making two entries into `aux` for each value of `x`. The point is that `s` may be of any length from 1 to 3 characters, and for the short lengths I do want two entries -- one with `s` as it it (because as I mentioned the last item in `row` may well be shorter than 3...), and one with it left-padded to a length of 3 with `0`s.

The sub-expression `('00'+s)[-3:]` computes "s left-padded with '0's to a length of 3" by taking the last 3 characters (that's the `[-3:]` slicing part) of the string obtained by placing zeros to the left of `s` (that's the `'00'+s` part). If `s` is already 3 characters long, the whole subexpression will equal `s` so the assignment to that entry of `aux` is useless but harmless, so I find it simpler to not even bother checking (prepending an `if len(s)<3:` would be fine too, matter of taste;-).

There are other approaches (e.g. formatting `x` again if needed) but this is hardly the crux of the code (it executes just 8 times to build up the auxiliary "lookup table", after all;-), so I didn't pay it enough attention.

...nor did I unit-test it, so it has a bug in one obscure corner case.  Can you see it...?

Suppose `row` has `'01'` as the last entry: THAT key, after my code's above has built `aux`, will not be present in `aux` (both `1` and `001` WILL be, but that's scanty consolation;-). In the code above I use the original `s`, `'1'`, and the length-three padded version, `'001'`, but the intermediate length-two padded version, oops, got overlooked;-).

So, here's a RIGHT way to do it...:

```
aux = {}
for x in range(8):
  s = format(x, 'b')
  aux[s] = x
  while len(s) < 3:
    s = '0' + s
    aux[s] = x
```

...no doubt simpler and more obvious, but, even more importantly, CORRECT;-).

Comment: That's kind of a mean trick you pull with the string indexing. You might want to explain what that's doing so the OP isn't tempted to copy/paste it into his code without understanding it.

Comment: Look, up in the sky! It codes, it explains, it even turns mistakes into lessons! It's SUPER MARTELLI, here to suck up my daily quota of upvotes!

Comment: @Chris, heh, I know of no programmer who makes no mistakes (that's why we have mandatory code reviews, unit testing, &c, after all;-) -- this one I spotted while explaining what I was doing (so thanks for prompting me to;-), so I thought it would be a particularly appropriate "teachable moment" ("you teach best, what you most need to learn", and clearly that makes me well suited to teaching the avoidance of excessive subtlety;-). Btw, it's martellibot, cfr http://www.google.com/search?q=martellibot -- nothing super about it;-)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this be easier:

(I wanted an array of the upper 3 bits of a variable that contained the integer 29)

format your variables and arrays first

a = ''

b = []

I stole this from a really good example in this forum, it formats the integer 29 into 5 bits, bits zero through four and puts the string of bits into the string variable "a".  [edited] Needed to change the format from 0:5b to 0:05b, in order to pad zeros when the integer is < 7.

a = '{0:05b}'.format(29)

look at your string variable

a

'11101'

split your string into an array

b[0:3] = a[0:3]

this is exactly what I wanted.

b

['1', '1', '1']

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with processing raw data of any kind, I'd like to recommend the excellent [bitstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring) module:

```
>>> import bitstring
>>> bits = bitstring.Bits('0b110101001')
>>> [b.uint for b in bits.cut(3)]
[6, 5, 1]
```

Description from the [home page](https://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/):

> A Python module that makes the creation, manipulation and analysis of
>   binary data as simple and natural as possible.
>
> Bitstrings can be constructed from integers, floats, hex, octal,
>   binary, bytes or files. They can also be created and interpreted using
>   flexible format strings.
>
> Bitstrings can be sliced, joined, reversed, inserted into,
>   overwritten, etc. with simple methods or using slice notation. They
>   can also be read from, searched and replaced, and navigated in,
>   similar to a file or stream.
>
> Internally the bit data is efficiently stored in byte arrays, the
>   module has been optimized for speed, and excellent code coverage is
>   given by over 400 unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers from Greg and Alex!  List comprehensions and slicing are so pythonic!
For short input strings I wouldn't bother with the dictionary lookup trick, but if the input string were longer, I would, as well as using gen-exps rather than list-comps,  i.e.:

row = list(thestring[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(thestring), 3))

and

numbers = list(aux[x] for x in row)

since gen-exp perform better.

Comment: Actually list comps perform the same or faster than gen. exprs (on examples I've tried). Don't do premature optimization in any case.

Comment: @JF, yep -- I do wish there was just ONE obvious way to do it, but, given that, alas, there are two, listcomps are indeed faster than `list(genexp)` (potentially by a sigificant factor) and should generally be preferred when both forms are possible and "obvious".

Comment: Dang! I stand corrected.  Thank you, JF and Alex.
My misconception of the genexp performance was rooted in a related Python idiom: that of using any [bounded] iterable to create a list:
   newlist = list(x)
is much faster (and more readable) than
   newlist = [y for y in x]

and since genexps essentially return an iterator, I wrongly assumed that list(some_genexp) would be faster than the corresponding listcomp... 
Lesson learned: I'll be using timeit more systematically.
<joke>BTW it's all Alex' fault! I got the list(x) idiom from Python cookBook.</joke>